# Electron BrowserView DOM manipulation from second BrowserView?

Tags: javascript, dom, google-chrome-extension, electron, preload

I am setting an Electron app that uses one main BrowserWindow and then I add two BrowserViews to it.

The idea is that one BrowserView acts as a side-bar and the other BrowserView loads an external URL.

My intention is to manipulate the external website from the DOM in the BrowserView, similar to Chrome Extensions when working with Background and Context scripts.

I have the code loading the app main window and the two views, with one local index loaded on one side and a website on the other. All good there (I just need to look into responsiveness of the views sizes, but that's for another time...)

Now, I tried using webPreferences with preload but I can't get my alert or console.log to trigger...

```
webPreferences: {
  preload: './preload.js',
}
```

I also tried using path: `preload: path.join(__dirname, 'preload.js')` but could not make it work either...

Any idea of how can I achieve this?

Do I need to abandon the preload method and look into IPC? I thought about from my html in one of the views to use IPC to communicate with the main process but the problem is them to communicate with the other view since it's an external website I don't know how to reacts to messages from main if I can't preload a background or a context script there... Makes sense?

Any help with be great, this is my first Electron app ever...

Comment: what do you mean you can't get your alert/console.log to trigger? Are you trying to have your sidebar run that code in the context of the main page? How are you testing this?

Comment: I was able to inject the js file with `preload: path.join(__dirname, '/preload.js'),` but that only works in my main BrowserWindow. I want to preload it in the attached BrowserView. It seems to be a bug in electron or something because the exact same instruction in the BrowserView does not preload the script...

Comment: preload should work in the BrowserView. we'll need to see some more code

Comment: Here is a simple example: https://github.com/laranjaquadrada/electron-quick-start
You can view the code here: https://gist.github.com/ckerr/d467fb8d1c884b306b0c5fc0f4d36fd5